# Show Riemann integrable of composite function with possible discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ be nonnegative continuous function on $[a,b]$ and $g$ be a convex function on $[0,\infty)$. Prove $g\circ f\in R[a,b]$.

If $g$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$, then it is trivial.

Now the problem comes: $g$ may not be continuous at $0$. So if $f(x)=0$ for some $x\in[a,b]$, then the above argument does not work. Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is true in general.

Now suppose $g$ is not continuous at $0$, then $g\circ f$ is discontinuous on the boundary of the set $\{x\in [a,b] : f(x) = 0\}$. In order for the function $g\circ f$ to be Riemann integrable, this boundary has to have Lebesgue measure zero. However, there exists non-negative continuous functions which the boundary of $\{x\in [a,b] : f(x) = 0\}$ has positive measure. The way you construct such function is the following: define a sequence of functions like below that takes the value $0$ on the Fat Cantor set (each cut is $\alpha 3^{-n}$ with $0<\alpha<1$ instead of $3^{-n}$). The sequence converges uniformly on the interval $[a,b]$, thus the limit is continuous.

[image]

Some basic properties of the Fat Cantor set:

1. it is closed, and has empty interior, thus its boundary is itself.
2. it has Lebesgue measure |b-a|(1-$\alpha$).

And you see the boundary of $\{x\in [a,b] : f(x) = 0\}$, which is exactly the Fat Cantor set.